# RJDBC dbListTables returning all tables that have ever existed, including system tables

Tags: mysql, r, jdbc, dbi, rjdbc

For a project i'm trying to use RJDBC to handle my importing/exporting of data.

This is the (minimum reproducable error) code I'm using:

```
library(RJDBC)
DB_DRIVER <- JDBC("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver", "mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(DB_DRIVER, "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdproj", "root", "root")
dbListTables(conn)
```

This returns a vector with length 327 including all tables that have ever existed in my MySQL installation and system tables. Instead of only the tables existing at that moment.

Result:

```
[1] "columns_priv"                                        
[2] "component"                                           
[3] "db"                                                  
...                   
[325] "x$waits_by_host_by_latency"                          
[326] "x$waits_by_user_by_latency"                          
[327] "x$waits_global_by_latency"
```

Expected result:

```
[1] "clean_event"                                         
[2] "clean_event_scaled"                                  
[3] "clean_ima_event"                                     
[4] "clean_interval"                                      
[5] "clean_match"                                         
[6] "clean_match_coordinates_statistics"                  
[7] "clean_match_coordinates_statistics_scaled"           
[8] "clean_match_report_statistics"                       
[9] "clean_match_teammates_statistics"                    
[10] "clean_player"
```

I've tried googling and reading obscure git issues/pull requests but I was not able to find anyone with the same or a similar problem.

I've tried using a different driver version.

It works as expected using MySQL() as a driver in the dbConnect call.
It behaves the same on my laptop and someone else's macbook.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: As mentioned here: https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbExistsTable.html dbExistsTable returns TRUE for all tables listed in dbListTable, so filtering those out does not do anything as the sets are the same.